# Excel Formula for Extracting Text with multiple closed parentheses at end of string

Tags: excel-formula

I have a cell in Excel that will have a variety of text, sometimes it will have one closed parenthesis at the end of the text, sometimes it will have two. There may also be open and closed parentheses within the text. I want a formula to extract the text between the first open parentheses and the last closed parentheses.
So far, I've tried:

```
=MID(C6,FIND("(",C6)+1,FIND(")",C6))
```

This formula still leaves the closed parenthesis at the end, when the text has a single closed parenthesis, and leaves both closed parentheses when the text has two closed parentheses at the end. For text that has open and closed parentheses in the middle, the result cuts off a portion of the text after the first closed parenthesis.
I've also tried this formula:

```
=MID(LEFT(C6,FIND(")",C6)-1),FIND("(",C6)+1,LEN(C6))
```

This formula works perfectly if the text only has one closed parenthesis at the end. However, if there are two closed parentheses at the end, it removes both, and I only need it to remove one. If I take out the -1 in the formula, it doesn't remove the closed parenthesis in the single closed parenthesis scenario. Plus, when there are open and closed parentheses within the text, it cuts off the text after the first closed parenthesis.

Comment: can you mock up some test data and expected output.  Make sure to cover all possible scenerios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last ")" is always located at the last position

This shorter formula can return the same result

In `B1`, copied down :

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)
```

[image]

And,

If the last ")" is not always located at the last position

Then,

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,LOOKUP(99,FIND(")",A1,ROW($1:$99)))-FIND("(",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.  I was trying everything.  Your first suggestion worked.  =MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("(",A1)-1)

Answer (score 0):

as best as I can tell, use this:

```
=MID(LEFT(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1,")","}}}",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",""))))-1),FIND("(",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]